# PHP date dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: php, date, zend-form

I would like to fill a date in as dd-mm-yyyy but I would like to save the date as Y-m-d in my database. What I have is this:

Form:

```
$factuurDatum = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('datum');
```

Controller:

```
$data = $addInkoopfactuur->getValues();    
$data['datum'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data['datum']));
```

But it doesn't work. I still get an error: '08-01-2014' and does not fit the date format 'yyyy-MM-dd'. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: can you paste the raw value of $data['datum'] ?

Comment: $data['datum']? and what is database table date column type

Comment: can you also specify which line of code produces that error?

Comment: var_dump(data['datum']); add in your question

Comment: plese add $data['datum'] =  "2009-01-31" to 2nd line. and check whether you get right answer. If got, the problem with  $data = $addInkoopfactuur->getValues();

Comment: if i hardcode $data['datnum'] = '08-01-2014' and run you code it gives exact output. what is your input?

Comment: Works fine here: https://eval.in/86801 .... your problem is no doubt elsewhere in the code.

Comment: thanks @DigitalChris the problem occurred in my form. ->addValidator( 'Date', true ) should be removed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the problem myself! the addvalidator('Date', true) should be deleted in my form! Because the validator will set my date as yyyy-mm-dd. My question was not answered clear enough, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Use this DateTime class

```
<?php
    $pubDt='07-01-2014';
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $pubDt);
    echo $newPubdate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

DEMO : https://eval.in/86800
Did you want it?

```
$data['datum'] = "15-10-2013";
$data['datum'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data['datum']));

echo $data['datum'] ;
```

OUTPUT:

```
2013-10-15
```

Comment: yes I do, but I want to fill in a date by myself in my Form. I do not want to give $data['datum'] a value in my controller.

Comment: I assigned it for testing purpose. Can you tell me what is the value of $data['datum'] before $data['datum'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data['datum'])); this line?

Comment: $factuurDatum = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('datum');
        $factuurDatum->setLabel('Datum op factuur')
  ->setAttrib('id', 'datepicker')
                ->addValidator(
                        'Date', 
                        true
                        )
                ->setAttrib('class', 'date-pick dp-applied')
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->setAttrib('size',8);

Comment: when you are posting your form what is the value of $data['datum']?

Comment: it is 0 because I need to fill in the value all by myself. I can fill in every value I want and that's what the value of $data['datum'] will be.

Comment: Got the problem myself! Thanks for your help. validator('Date', true) should be deleted in my form!

Comment: Sorry, thought the problem was in my controller, never thought it was in my form. Thanks anyways!